# Shortcut to execute output of last command in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Is there any shortcut to execute the output of the previous command, such as executing whatever is found by the `locate` command?

For instance, if I run this `locate` command and get this output...

```
root@kali:~/scripts# locate nasm_shell
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/tools/nasm_shell.rb
```

Is there any way to execute that `nasm_shell.rb` command with a shortcut? Just being lazy and trying to avoid copying and pasting the full command path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(locate nasm_shell)
```

or

```
`locate nasm_shell`
```

You can use backticks ``` `` ``` or `$()` to execute the command in a subshell, for instance:

```
user@host$ which df
/bin/df
user@host$ `which df`
Filesystem          1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda1              498532    199535    268738  43% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-home 412718256 232104076 159626276  60% /home
```

If there is more than a single line of output, you'll need to use `grep` or some other tool to select the right output:

For instance, the following has more than the output I want, to find `mkdir`

```
user@host$ locate mkdir
/bin/mkdir
/opt/project-neon5/include/KF5/KIOCore/kio/mkdirjob.h
/usr/lib/klibc/bin/mkdir
/usr/lib/mc/fish/mkdir
/usr/share/aclocal-1.14/mkdirp.m4
/usr/share/man/man1/gvfs-mkdir.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mkdir.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man2/mkdir.2.gz
/usr/share/man/man2/mkdirat.2.gz
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_mkdir
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/doc/bundler-1.3.5/ri/Bundler/mkdir_p-c.ri
```

I just want `mkdir` that lives in `/bin`. Using grep to select the correct output, then adding an argument to the output of the subshell:

```
user@host$ $(locate mkdir | grep "^\/bin") test-directory && ls -ld test-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Nov 15 21:18 test-directory
```

Note the use of the alternate syntax `$()`

Comment: Thanks - figured I'd cover all the use cases and generalize the answer some...

Answer (score 0):

This should work using [`eval`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/eval) as well as [`locate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) coupled with `$()` like this:

```
eval $(locate nasm_shell)
```

But the risk with using this is let’s say you have multiple files with the name `nasm_shell` on the system. Then that command would fail since it would attempt to try and run the full output of the `locate` command. But if you are 100% positive what you are looking for is in one file/script like `nasm_shell.rb`, then this would be fine.

Comment: The `eval` isn't necessary, the subshell is sufficient with bash/zsh, etc. `eval` is mostly for constructing commands requiring concatenation of strings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses